# Unit testing SBT code within the local project

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt

I have an SBT project, within which I have defined a [source generator](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html) that parses some DB migration scripts in order to make the current DB version available to the application at compile-time.

For example, I might have the following resources:

```
subproject1/src/main/resources/db/migration/
  |- V1__Baseline.sql
  |- V2__AddCustomerTable.sql
  |- V2_1__Refactor.sql
```

And I would require my source generator to create a scala object with the field `val version = "2.1"`.

The SBT project is structured as:

```
project/
  |- build.sbt
  |- SchemaVersionParser.scala
```

Where `SchemaVersionParser` defines the utility functions that are used by `build.sbt` in order to parse the resources and generate the appropriate file.

Now since this is a key component of my app, I'd like to ensure that the functions in `SchemaVersionParser` which extract and sort the versions are unit tested.

Is there any supported means of unit testing SBT code residing locally in the one project? I know I can do this if I create a separate SBT plugin, however it'd be nice if I could avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SBT build definitions are SBT projects. So put test code in `project/src/test/scala` should be able to access `SchemaVersionParser`, and to launch the tests you just do `sbt test` in `project` directory.